# function to create/generate random numbers

Tags: python, function

I need help to create a function that generates 8 digit random numbers with 2 favorite number sequencing anywhere.

```
def favourite_number(first, second):
    phone = random.randint(600000,699999)
    generate = first,second,phone
    return generate
print(favourite_number(8,6))
```

This is the result I am getting but I want it to be randomly placed anywhere not compulsorily in the beginning and that too without comma.

```
"C:\Users\WIN Ultimate\PycharmProjects\new\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/WIN Ultimate/PycharmProjects/new/Numbergenerator.py"
(8, 6, 699936)
```

Comment: The commas are just part of the way that lists and tuples are printed.

Answer (score 1):

Use a list instead of tuple, so you can insert in a random index.

```
def favourite_number(first, second):
    phone = random.randint(600000,699999)
    generate = [first, second]
    generate.insert(random.randint(0, 2), phone)
    return generate
```

If you want to print it without commas, use:

```
print(" ".join(map(str, favourite_number(8, 6))))
```

Comment: This is the output I am getting:   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/WIN Ultimate/PycharmProjects/new/Numbergenerator.py", line 20, in <module>
    print(" ".join(map(str, favourite_number(8, 6))))
NameError: name 'favourite_number' is not defined

Comment: I had a typo in the function name, it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is what you're looking for (:

```
import random
def favourite_number(first, second):
    phone = random.randint(600000,699999)
    generate = first,second,phone
    generate = [str(x) for x in generate]
    return ''.join(generate)
print(favourite_number(8,6))
```

There are many more ways to do it!!

Comment: Every time I run code the 2 digits are at beginning I want them to be anywhere indexing randomly not at a specific index 0 and 1. Example:- 25154862, 25154286, 55861355 at every different run code I want different value.

Comment: I've just edited my answer so it'll match your requirements (:

Comment: If you've found my answer helpful I'd love it if you could accept it for my reputation please (: